# Pgsql query with empty HTML tags

Tags: postgresql

I have a `body` column (data type `text`) in a `posts` table which is storing HTML string.

How can i write a query to get all the `posts` with `body` containing at least one empty link (e.g. `<a href=".." whatever></a>`)?

Comment: Use the appropriate regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE body ~* '^[^\>]*(>){1}</a>$';
```

It means that empty links must have only one single '>' character before the ending tag.

Comment: This will select `<a href="">hi></a>` which is actually a valid link

Comment: I've updated my answer to take account of this special case.